# Reflection and loading of dlls

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a generc vb.net import program I am loading in the dlls usings this method But I cant figure out how to unload the dll once finished with it . Can someone help it just hangs in memory and of course cant see it in task manager so nead a way to close the dll after

```
  Public Shared Function  CreateInstance(ByVal Plugin As AvailablePlugin) As Object
   Dim objDLL As [Assembly]
    Dim objPlugin As Object

    Try
        'Load dll
        objDLL = [Assembly].LoadFrom(Plugin.AssemblyPath)

        'Create and return class instance
        objPlugin = objDLL.CreateInstance(Plugin.ClassName)
    Catch e As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return objPlugin
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Dynamic Loading/Unloading of DLLs Redux (using AppDomain, of course)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462525/c-sharp-dynamic-loading-unloading-of-dlls-redux-using-appdomain-of-course)

Comment: Also, I would suggest you look at the Managed Extensibility Framework which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson as this is vb.net dont no how its a duplicate question

Comment: @RB been trying to find good vb.net examples of that one just laoding an example dlll but no luck it alls sesm to be for c# programmers

Comment: 99.99% of it is .net the vb or c# bit is just syntax.