# What options do I have to dynamically access a class in another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a ASP.NET MVC application and a plugin that needs to write to the web.config file. For various reasons, I've found that the most appropriate way to do this is during compilation using MSBuild configuration, so I have created an executable distributed with my plugin to be called here with appropriate parameters for resolving consumer-application dependencies like the path to the config file.

The plugin is configurable, and the definition for this must be in the consumer application in a specific class.

Now the plugin-executable has to be able to read this class, but we can not have any hard-coded dependencies since the plugin should be distributable and used in many different applications.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462525/c-sharp-dynamic-loading-unloading-of-dlls-redux-using-appdomain-of-course) here on SO about dynamically loading/unloading DLLs, and my question is if this is **the** approach to use, while passing in the relevant parameters as arguments to the exe, or do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes but you can do it in two different ways.

If you want to unload the class yes you need to create a new AppDomain, use it and unload it in the end, to do this you need a class that implements `MarshalByRefObject` it's much more complicated.

If the class can live during the lifetime of the client application you just need to load your plugin to the current AppDomain.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName);
```

I strongly recommend that the instance you are loading implements a specific Interface so you can inspect a folder for DLL's like this

```
var ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
ass.DefinedTypes.Where(t => t.ImplementedInterfaces
                             .Any(i => i.AssemblyQualifiedName ==
                                       typeof(<Defined Interface>).AssemblyQualifiedName))
```

this will return a list of types that implement your interface so you just need to use the above code to create one instance.

I think that to work with msbuild you need to take the first approach and do all the load unload and usage inside of the class that implements `MarshalByRefObject` don't quote me on this one.